# Can the bootstrap accordion control a DIV?

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-accordion

I am wondering if the bootstrap accordion can control a DIV without javascript.
I want to achieve this effect: https://testbuttons.bss.design/accordion.html
but now I am using:

```
$('#btn_lesson-1').click(function(){
    $('#lesson-1').show();
    $('#lesson-2').hide();
    $('#lesson-3').hide();
});

$('#btn_lesson-2').click(function(){
    $('#lesson-2').show();
    $('#lesson-1').hide();
    $('#lesson-3').hide();
});

    
$('#btn_lesson-3').click(function(){
    $('#lesson-3').show();
    $('#lesson-1').hide();
    $('#lesson-2').hide();
    
});
```

But it gets annoying to create code for more lessons.

Or maybe there is some other way to achieve thisņ Maybe some simple CMS?

Thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap, the accordion should already be opening and closing elements by default based on the clicked element. See this example: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#accordion-example

Comment: I know, accordion works fine by itself. its the divs with video that are hidden and shown on the accordion clicks. So the question is if I can show and hide the div withhout javascript.